# Is it possible to ng-repeat through specified list of object attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have something like:

```
$scope.listOfAttributes = ["someThings", "yetMoreThings"]     

$scope.whatever = {
    someThings: "stuff",
    otherThings: "Also stuff",
    yetMoreThings: "still stuff"
};
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="thing in listOfAttributes">{{ whatever.thing }}</li>
</ul>
```

or would I have to process it before hand like:

```
$scope.generatedObject = {}
$scope.listOfAttributes.forEach(function(thing)){
    $scope.generatedObject[thing] = $scope.whatever[thing];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change,

```
<li ng-repeat="thing in listOfAttributes">{{ whatever.thing }}</li>
```

to

```
<li ng-repeat="thing in listOfAttributes">{{ whatever[thing] }}</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use bracket notation just like you would in normal javascript code:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="thing in listOfAttributes">{{ whatever[thing] }}</li>
</ul>
```